# How can I get the value in JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get the result using the conversation API of IBM Watson using this code:

```
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import ConversationV1
conversation = ConversationV1(
username='******',
password='*****',
version='2016-09-20')
workspace_id = '***'
response = conversation.message(workspace_id=workspace_id, message_input={
'text': 'hi'})
print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

Running this code will print this JSON:

```
{
"intents": [
{
  "confidence": 1, 
  "intent": "greating"
 }
], 
"entities": [], 
"context": {
"conversation_id": "d6952ab6-e27e-4c50-8b90-01f3087bcc0e", 
"system": {
  "dialog_stack": [
    {
      "dialog_node": "root"
    }
  ], 
  "dialog_request_counter": 1, 
  "dialog_turn_counter": 1, 
  "branch_exited": true, 
  "_node_output_map": {
    "greeting": [
      0
    ]
  }, 
  "branch_exited_reason": "completed"
 }
}, 
"input": {
"text": "hi"
}, 
"output": {
  "log_messages": [], 
  "nodes_visited": [
  "greeting"
  ], 
  "text": [
  "Hi I am Nao Nice to meet you"
  ]
 }, 
 "alternate_intents": false
}
```

I've tried many way but can't decode this JSON. I just want to get the output text: "Hi I am Nao Nice to meet you". How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json is a serialization format, which is not intended to be directly interacted with without de-serializing first. Rather than trying to extract information from the json string, just extract it from the dictionary you used to create the json string.

```
print(response["output"]["text"][0])
```

Comment: Great <3  my way is try to decoding the json.dump data so i can't get anything <3 Many thank you

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Kevin, you can access individual node segments as follows:

```
response['output']['text'][0]
```

Watson conversation response tends to be all connected, so you can use this method.

```
'<p>'.join(response['output']['text'])
```

That will embed a HTML paragraph break between each array item and return it as a full string.

Or if you want take action on each object of the output text.

```
for text in response['output']['text']:
    print(text)
```